# Wordpress REST API create custom endpoint that uses custom table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, rest

Is it possible to create a Custom endpoint that is connected to the same database but with a custom table? if yes, how?

for example :

wp_TempTable (Custom Table)

I want to access this with a custom endpoint... I have searched multiple forums and sites but no luck..

Comment: What do you mean "a custom table"?  The API exposes data from multiple tables, what are you thinking of for having a "custom" table instead?

Comment: I needed the custom table to store some Account Information that came from a 3rd party client which is what the client wanted... but after finding out that the API only uses the default tables (wp_posts and wp_users)... 

so I searched for some other way to make the API connect to a separate table but to no avail...

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. This does not use the Controller pattern recommended by Wordpress but gets the job done, where the job is to convert incoming json into a row in your custom table (here called `restaurants`).

```
function handle_post( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $item = $request->get_json_params();

    $fields = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach($item as $key => $val) {
        array_push($fields, preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $key));
        array_push($values, $wpdb->prepare('%s', $val));
    }
    $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
    $values = implode(", ", $values);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `restaurants` ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
    $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    return $list;
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'restos/v1', '/post', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'handle_post',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
    }
  ) );
} );
```

Comment: I'm getting 403 (Forbidden) any idea ? Thank you

Comment: You are creating a gigantic hole of security and space for a lot of bugs by not using wpdb->prepare; just try to see what happens when a value has a single quote in it

Comment: (Just fixed it in this answer)